# TYPO3 DCE to TYPO3FLUX

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-dce

Hello guys im totally new to TYPO3 and I received a task to rewrite the DCE syntax to flux. Can anybody explain it to me how it works? do I need flux for each?

```
    <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference">
    <vhs:resource.image identifier="{fileReference.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" as="image1">
        <vhs:variable.set name="imageSrc1" value="{image1.0.source}" />
    </vhs:resource.image>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually DCE is an extension which allows you to create custom elements and you can create elements from Backend of TYPO3. Flux is a different method to create custom elements which creates elements using the viewhelpers in the template.

Here you can find the documentation of the flux https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/introduction/

Both methods are different so you will need to re-create each and every element and also needs to do data entries if site is already filled with the data.

Comment: ok thank u , but in this case what can i use for dce:fal  but in flux

Comment: Here is the relevant viewhelper: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/Inline/FalViewHelper.html

You can find other alternative view helpers at: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/.

Please accept it as answer if you find it helpful!